# How to put multiple horizontally tables in jsPDF-autotable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am new to JSPDF and I don't understand how to make 2 tables appear next to each others.

I've tried the multiple example in examples/examples.js

```js
var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF('p','pt','a4'); 
var pageNumber = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages()
doc.autoTable({
  startY: 240,
  showHead: 'firstPage',
  html:   '#table',
  styles: {  overflow: 'hidden'},
  margin: { left: 107 },
});

doc.setPage(pageNumber)

doc.autoTable({
  startY: 240,
  showHead: 'firstPage',
  html:   '#table',
  styles: { overflow: 'hidden'},
  margin: { right: 107 },
});
```

It only displays them on top of each other with a margin of 107 horizontally I presume

[image]

Instead of :

[image]

I don't understand what I am missing since I copied the example and replaced the data by an html table.